# Encrypt file by blocks

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, rsa, public-key-encryption

I have a large file that I am trying to encrypt with RSA. Yes, I know that hybrid encryption is typically used in this case, but I would like to use standard public key encryption to see the difference in efficiency.

In order to encrypt such a large file, I understand that I must encrypt block by block. After receiving, an error that stated my byte array was too large to encrypt with RSA-2048, I reduced the byte array to 245 bytes. A byte array of 246 bytes works fine, but it also only works for 246 bytes which is my issue. I need to encrypt the whole file with RSA-2048.

After researching RSA-2048 cryptography to get a better understanding, and block by block encryption, I am still confused about implementing block by block encryption with RSA-2048. This is my first time implementing cryptography in any language. Below is my code pertaining to encrypting the large file with an RSA public key.

Any suggestions as to how I can encrypt the whole large file block by block with RSA are appreciated.

Comment: No, not "I know that hybrid encryption is typically used in this case" but never be knowledgable developers. Symmetric and asymmetric encryption each have their place based on their characteristics, use them that way just as one would not use 1000 mini-cars to deliver the concrete for a skyscraper. There there is the question why are you even using asymmetric encryption (RSA), do you have a need for both a public and private key pair? Finally, I sure hope this will never be used in production code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, regardless of what you might say, **you should never use RSA as a block cipher**.  If you did this in production code and someone found out, you would most likely get fired.

But...

- You should read upto ~246 bytes from the `FileInputStream`.
- Encrypt the result of this using RSA.
- Write the encrypted block to the `FileOutputStream`.

Your code doesn't do this because:

- You return the first block of ciphertext immediately:

  `inputfile= cipher.doFinal(block);
  return inputfile;`
- You don't do anything with the result.

Comment: Please see my update. I am confuse as to what I would return.

Comment: @SamHunt I think you should start from scratch and maybe learn about while loops, file I/O first. Your code makes no sense.  You shouldn't return there cause then the code only loops once?

Comment: I read up about while loops, and file I/O. I am teaching myself so please sir, can you explain where I would return. I apologize for my confusion, but I have spent many hours working hard on this. Thank you.

Comment: @SamHunt Return when you are finished looping?  I'm not really sure what you mean.  Looks like you are returning null anyway so just make the return type void.

Comment: Sir, I took several of your suggestions, and started from scratch. Please see my update. I understand that I must return when done looping, but I am not sure where to put the return because if I change the 'return null' to the encrypted byte array, I receive an error as the byte array is not in that scope. Can you please help me return the value properly? I am new, and am trying to teach myself. Thank you.

Comment: @SamHunt The code you have won't do what you want.  You should open the `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` once, not every time inside the loop.  And the point I'm making is that you ** don't need to return anything**.  Change the method return type to void.

Comment: I realize that I did not explain this; I need to return the whole encrypted file in the form of a byte array for decryption later (I have the decryption solved already). Thank you for your patience.

Comment: @SamHunt That kind of changes everything.  Have a look at `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

Comment: I apologize. Please see my update. I have tried to incorporate the opening the FileInputStream once, and using ByteArrayOutputStream. Again, I am not sure how to return after full encryption.

Comment: @SamHunt I'm sorry but I don't think I can help you any further, you either don't understand what I'm saying or just aren't competent enough to implement it. Sorry. Good luck.